# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.naive_bytes'; 'sklearn' is not a package

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, gaussian, sklearn-pandas

I have already installed sklearn, but still when I run the program it shows error. When I try to check if it is install it says requirements are already satisfied.

```
import numpy as np 
X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
Y = np.array([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
clf.fit(X, Y)
GaussianNB()
print(clf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
clf_pf = GaussianNB()
clf_pf.partial_fit(X, Y, np.unique(Y))
GaussianNB()
print(clf_pf.predict([[-0.8, -1]]))
```

The output for the same is as given in the image below.
[image]

Comment: I also tried pip install -U sklearn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rename your file from "sklearn.py" to something else. Try renaming it to "foo.py" then run

> python foo.py

Comment: Thanks Adam. I didn't know that was the problem.

Comment: Glad to help! :)

Answer (score 3):

From what I can see it´s installed for python3 and you use python2.7 Wich also is obsolete now.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is because the file you're using is also called sklearn, try renaming it

Comment: Thanks Kathy Rindhoops